# When screen is smaller then x y use overflow

Tags: html, css, overflow

I want my body to stop getting smaller when resizing when it's at x, y small. And when it's that small I want to use a overflow.

Comment: you can also use min-height and max-height. or use @media

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use media queries. They allow different CSS behavior depending on the size of the browser viewport.

In your case, type

```
@media (min-height: Y), @media (min-width: X) {
    /* your css for greater than X,Y */
}


@media (min-height: 0), @media (min-width: 0) {
    /* your css for smaller than X,Y */
}
```